# How do I abstract out the select in this Entity Framework IQueryable query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression, iqueryable

I have the following Entity Framework queries:

```
var items1 = items.Select(x=> x.Prop1)
                  .Select(...).OrderBy(..).ToArray();

var items2 = items.Select(x=> x.Prop2)
                  .Select(...).OrderBy(..).ToArray();

var items3 = items.Select(x=> x.Prop3)
                  .Select(...).OrderBy(..).ToArray();
```

As you can see this is repeated code.

The following `.Select(...).OrderBy(..).ToArray();` is exactly the same.

I can't seem to find a way to extract the first select

Something like,

```
var temp = Select(x=> x.Prop1);
```

I want to ultimately turn that into a for loop using reflection, but the above statement gives me a compile error.

The application is on .Net 4 so I don't have access to anything new that may have come up to solve this problem.

Comment: Prop1\2\3 are all of the same type?

Comment: Yes they are all string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move it to another function:

```
ResultType[] Execute(IQueryable<TypeOfProps> query) {
     return query.Select(...).OrderBy(..).ToArray()
}
```

If you don't want to create separate function - create anonymous:

```
Func<IQueryable<TypeOfProps>,ResultType[]>> execute = (query) => 
    query.Select(...).OrderBy(..).ToArray();
var items1 = execute(items.Select(x=> x.Prop1));
var items2 = execute(items.Select(x=> x.Prop2));
var items3 = execute(items.Select(x=> x.Prop3))
```

Comment: In the second one the sequence of select is being altered. Will it affect the results?

Comment: Altered how? You said all 3 are "exactly the same".

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method that given the first `Select`s lambda, calculates the result:

```
ResultType[] YouCarefullyChoosenName(Expression<Func<InputType, string>> propSelector)
{
    return items.Select(propSelector).Select(...).OrderBy(..).ToArray();
}

var items1 = YouCarefullyChoosenName(x => x.Prop1);
var items2 = YouCarefullyChoosenName(x => x.Prop2);
var items3 = YouCarefullyChoosenName(x => x.Prop3);
```

Comment: I prefer this over Evk's answer, because it also abstracts away the first `Select` call.